# Does the Frog Rider trait of a Bullywug Royal work with Giant Toads?

Tags: dnd-5e, monsters, mounted-combat, animals, ghosts-of-saltmarsh

The *Ghosts of Saltmarsh* WOTC Hardcover contains a few new statblocks, including the [Bullywug Royal](https://www.dndbeyond.com/monsters/bullywug-royal), who has the following trait:

> ***Frog Rider.*** The royal has advantage on melee attacks made while riding a frog mount.

However, the Bullywug Royal is a Medium creature, meaning it needs to mount a Large or larger creature. The largest frog creature is the [Giant Frog](https://www.dndbeyond.com/monsters/giant-frog), which is Medium, thus cannot be mounted by the Royal. That being said, the [Giant Toad](https://www.dndbeyond.com/monsters/giant-toad) is a Large creature, and the fluff text of Royals says:

> A bullywug royal is often accompanied by and mounted astride a giant toad.

Thus, does a Bullywug Royal benefit from its "Frog Rider" trait while riding a Giant Toad?

Comment: yes, if you are playing in my campaign.  Where is this question coming from?  Do you consider the words "toad" and "frog" so foreign that some distinction needs to be made?

Answer (score 4):

Unless "frog mount" is defined as a specific thing, I would allow it. I do not have the material to read so I'm going off of the text you shared, but from the fluff it seems like the idea is that they ride a rather large amphibian that moves by hopping. And while they are riding that frog-like creature that they are known for riding, they get a bonus thing.

Again, I do not have the material as reference, so unless they are given a specific frog mount and stats to go with it (like the mount has some sort of battle training), I would just roll with it.

Would it break the game?  If allowing the riders to receive the bonus on a toad instead of a frog would make the game unduly difficult then don't do it. If it's just a matter of flavor then I think it would be fine.

Comment: Yes, thank you for the correction. I will try to gather some words to add to the rhetorical at the end.